# can't access from outside with nginx reverse proxy in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, server, duck-dns

i know there are lots of similar questions about but no one help me.
I have a linux server running nginx reverse proxy in docker, a duckdns domain created,opened my router port 80 and 443. I can't access from outside with my domain name or public ip, it seems like my router refuses external request. I tried with lots of configuration, follow lots of guides on web... I get crazy to solve this problem.
I think problem is before nginx, so i not post my nginx conf. If can help, I will post it.
Hope someone can help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that could be causing the issue with your router refusing external requests. Here are a few things to check:

Make sure that your router's firewall is configured to allow incoming connections on ports 80 and 443. Some routers have a built-in firewall that needs to be configured to allow traffic through specific ports.

Confirm that your router is properly forwarding incoming requests to the correct IP address and port on your network. This is typically done through a feature called port forwarding.

Check your router's security settings to ensure that it is not blocking incoming requests based on the source IP address or domain name. Some routers have the option to block incoming requests from specific IP addresses or domain names.

Confirm that your Linux server is properly configured to handle incoming requests. This includes checking that your Nginx reverse proxy is running and properly configured to forward requests to the correct IP address and port.

Verify that your DNS is pointing to the right IP address, you can use online tools like https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to check this.

Check if your router have any VPN or proxy service enabled, which could be affecting the incoming request.

Check if your ISP is blocking incoming connection to your public IP address.

It's also possible that there might be a problem with your router's firmware or hardware, in that case, you may need to contact the manufacturer for further assistance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. 
I opened port 80 and 443 and firewall seems allow traffic, there aren't no rule about. 

My linux server settings is properly config because from inside i can reach my nginx instance with internal IP. 

No VPN or Proxy service enabled. 

How can I check if my ISP is blocking incomint connection? Sorry but i'm a bit noobie about

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).